# Excel if cell exceeds certain value use difference

Tags: excel, excel-2011

I can't come up with the right formula for this.

Cell B3 contains a value. In cell C3 is the formula which should calculate: if B3 exceeds 1500, i want it to display the difference.
E.g. IF value of B3 is 1600, C3 should display 100.

Thanks, can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to show the value of `B3` when that value is less than or equal to 1500, and to show the difference if it is greater, use the following:

```
=IF(B3>1500,B3-1500,B3)
```

If you want it to show nothing if it is less than or equal to 1500, use:

```
=IF(B3>1500,B3-1500,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=if(B3>1600;B3-A3;"")
```

Honestly i didn't catch the other operand of the difference you describe, but that is the If formula..

hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

=IF(B3>1500;B3-A3;"")
As you mentioned if value is greater than 1500 so the formula should be as above.

Comment: This seems to be a comment to the answer of @Mark. In this case you should have commented on his answer. If your intention was to mention that the 1600 should be a 1500, then you should have proposed an edit on the other answer.